# Why wont my while loop work when adding my def function

Tags: python-3.x

This is my code below and I cant seem to make my while loop run continuosly.

```
#alphabet list 
alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']



# user input message
text = input("Type your message:\n")
# user input shift amount
shift = int(input("Type the shift number:\n"))
  
      
# def function
def encode(plain_text, shift_amount):
  cipher_text = ''
  for letter in plain_text:
    position = alphabet.index(letter)
    new_position = position + shift_amount
    new_letter = alphabet[new_position]
    cipher_text += new_letter
  print(f'The encoded string is: {cipher_text}')

encode(plain_text = text, shift_amount = shift)

while True:
  if text != 'q':
    continue
```

I am not sure if I set this up correctly.

Comment: You haven't specified what you are trying to do. Your while loop can only enter an infinite loop, regardless of the value of text, as you have no means of breaking the loop. I assume you meant to put the input sections inside the loop?

Answer (score 0):

Executed like this, your prompt will ask for two inputs (your message and the shift number), then execute `encode`. Then it'll enter the `while True` loop and loop forever. Why?

Two reasons:

1. If you didn't input `q` at the first step, you will never meet the condition
2. Even though you did set `text = "q"`, your loop will never stop. You need to use the `break` statement to make an infinite loop stop:

```py
while True:
    if text == 'q':
        break
```

I think what you want is:

```py
while True:
    text = input("Type your message (or q to quit):\n")
    shift = int(input("Type the shift number:\n"))
    if text == 'q':
        break

    encode(text, shift_amount=shift)
```

Thus, your code will loop and ask & encode an input until to type "q"

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the following lines inside the while loop for it to continuously run (as I think you want):

```
# user input message
text = input("Type your message:\n")
# user input shift amount
shift = int(input("Type the shift number:\n"))

encode(plain_text = text, shift_amount = shift)
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in other answers, you should call `input` and `encode` inside the while loop. However, I think only the first `input` should be before the `if` clause like so:

```py
while True:
    # user input message
    text = input("Type your message:\n")
    if text != 'q':
        break

    # user input shift amount
    shift = int(input("Type the shift number:\n"))

    encode(plain_text=text, shift_amount=shift)
```

Also, you don't need to define `alphabet` as a list of characters, you can simply define it as a string:

```py
alphabet = 'abcdefghifklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
```

or, even better, just import it from `string`:

```py
import string

alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase
```